# problem in reading txt file in php

Tags: php, html, file

im looking for a way to read a file into an array and get what i want .

this is the code i used to read a file into an array

```
$Path = 'dewp/pix/info.txt';
$productsArray = file($dirPath, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
foreach ($productsArray as $key => &$product) {
    $arr = explode("\t", $product);
    $product =array('album=' => $arr[0], 'singer=' => $arr[1], 'info=' => $arr[2]);
}
echo "$product['album']";
```

and my txt file contains :

```
album= Prisoner
singer= Jackobson
info= Love song about GOD , so so so so .
```

but nothing happened and i couldnt get  album - singer or info string !

i need to explode special strings like  album= to find out the values !

Comment: You are exploding with Tabs as Delimiter. Are you sure they aint just regular spaces? Also, do you want `$product['album']` to contain *Prisoner* or *album=* The whole code does not seem to correspond with the text file you show.

Comment: i think im totally wrong !  cause i need to explode album=  and then find out the values 
can u post an answer on how to explode special string and find the value !?

Comment: Can there be more than one album in the text file?

Answer (score 4):

That data looks like `.ini` files, why don't you try using `parse_ini_file()`, like

```
<?php
$Path = 'dewp/pix/info.txt';
$product = parse_ini_file($path);
echo $product['album'];
```

If you have multiple products, you could have the files like

```
[some_product]
artist=Foo
singer=Bar
info=Lorem ipsum bla bla

[other_product]
artist=Foobar
singer=The Dude
info=Dolor sit amet bla bla bla
```

and do

```
<?php
$Path = 'dewp/pix/info.txt';
$products = parse_ini_file($path, true);
echo $products['some_product']['album'];
```

Also, in your code, you set a variable `$Path`, and then use `$dirPath` on the next line. And it overwrites the `$product` variable for each line in the loop.

Comment: it works on localhost but not in website online mode , it cant only fetch the name $product['album']  and just the $product['info'] works

Comment: Are you saying that it half-works on the production server? If so, check that the file it uses is the same, has correct permissions, proper character set and line-endings.

Answer (score 2):

That's because each line in your file is an element in the array, the `file()` function does not create any keys, you have to split each element by the '= ' string to get an array of two elements (a key and a variable).

```
$path = 'dewp/pix/info.txt';
$lines = file($path, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$product = array();
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $arr = explode("= ", $line);
    $product[$arr[0]] = $arr[1];
}
echo "{$product['album']}";
```

**Note:** The `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` flag just removes the '\n' at the end of each array element.

Comment: nop . i used you code but no result !  are you sure about the code you wrote ?!